# having trouble installing reactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am having having trouble installing reactJS using the following guide:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

I am using:
npm 4.2.0
node 7.10.0
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

This is the error I am getting:

```
[root@webdev2 reactJSApp]# npm start

> test@1.0.0 start /opt/swtapps/reactJSApp
> webpack-dev-server --hot

✖ ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/node/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs test
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-16T19_07_33_854Z-debug.log
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: That's an old tutorial. <webpack@2 used `module.loaders`. It's called `module.rules` in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is outdated. Loaders in Webpack 4 are defined as:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      // options for the loader
    },
  ],
}
```

I'd recommend reading the [documentation of webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) for issues like these.